# Wacom Bamboo Ink Stylus makes notifications appear on screen contact

Tags: drivers, notification, touchscreen, tablet, wacom

Whenever I have my Wacom Bamboo Ink stylus touch the screen, a notification appears that says "Tablet battery low. Tablet is in low power (6%)". I assume this is a driver issue, since I am not using a tablet, but a stylus on a touchscreen laptop (Lenovo Yoga 720). I've done an update and also perused https://linuxwacom.github.io/ but I do not see any discernible way to fix this. The stylus works fine otherwise, those constant notifications are just annoying.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a Lenovo stylus on a Lenovo Flex 5 running Ubuntu 20.

Comment: I fixed this by changing the batteries and restarting. Strange because the previous batteries were not low, but it worked for me